# How to update a field by another field value in doctrine odm

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, doctrine-odm

I've searched in google for 2 hours but I've got nothing.

I have following document :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61990502a41b9b0d1a369ed2"
  },
  "service": "reservation",
  "expert": {
    "$binary": "qg+a+2WkTeOTvQc9RgBKyg==",
    "$type": "4"
  },
  "rate": {
    "counts": {
      "1": 3,
      "2": 1,
      "3": 2,
      "4": 5,
      "5": 4
    },
    "average": 2,
    "total": 15
  },
  "comments": 2
}
```

I want to update field "rate.average" by current value of it's field by Doctrine ODM like below :

```
public function updateCountAndRate(string $service, string $expert, float $rate, bool $comment = false)
    {
        $QB = $this->createQueryBuilder();
        $QB->field(sprintf("rate.counts.%d", $rate))->inc(1);
        $QB->field('rate.average')->set(sprintf('$rate.average*$rate.total+%f/$total+1', $rate));
        $QB->field('rate.total')->inc(1);
        $QB->updateOne()->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```

But nothing changed for average rate.

I can't update field value by another field value in doctrine !?

Even I tried following syntax but nothing happened.

```
$QB->field('rate.average')->set('$total');
```

Comment: Two things: 1) best is to set query builder explicitly in update mode with `updateOne()`/`updateMulti()` (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.2/reference/query-builder-api.html#updating-multiple-documents) 2) Query object has a `->debug()` method with which you can check how generated query looks like

Comment: @malarzm thanks for your comment 
1.I set it but forgot to put it here in my method and edited my question